# Need to delete a particular block

Tags: linux, perl, shell

From file,

```
====================================
{
        "id": "ffc131ff-1793-4109-940f-5b537f7061cf",
        "securityResourceId": "48d0eeff-690d-4c2c-b6f9-9b25315f9ca3",
        "name": "Dev-bpimdmgr-idev3-01",
        "active": true,
        "licensed": true,
        "licenseType": "AUTHORIZED",
        "status": "ONLINE",
        "tags": []
    },
    {
        "id": "82db2888-7a2f-48fe-bc25-26a5e28bb340",
        "securityResourceId": "5a437865-6ced-402e-ac47-dd38191e5696",
        "name": "obiee-cmixdmgr-nprd3-01",
        "active": true,
        "licensed": true,
        "licenseType": "AUTHORIZED",
        "status": "ONLINE",
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": "fbf62944-a8a4-4a22-8e75-cd8d88eacaff",
                "name": "obiee-tag",
                "color": "#32cd32",
                "description": "obiee tag for version import",
                "objectType": "Agent"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I want to delete tags[] block including where are there inside this block. through perl or shell script

Regards,
Kalaiyarasan

Comment: And what is your Question?

Comment: If you can transform this to proper JSON, the operation would be as easy as `jq 'del(.tags)'`

Comment: Thanks Anubhava.. Can you please how delete through perl ?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module:

```
use JSON qw{ from_json to_json };

my $struct = from_json("[$input]");
delete $_->{tags} for @$struct;
print to_json($struct);
```

Comment: probably want `to_json($struct, { pretty => 1 } )`.  I would also add `canonical => 1`.   Note that the order of attributes will be changed (either way).

Comment: I am getting the error that  ....     malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 ["$VAR1 = [\n         ..."] at agent.pl line 21

Comment: @Kalaiyarasan: Oh yes, outer square brackets are missing. Check the update.